# Setting the left margin when elements to the left of 2 or more objects are different lengths

Tags: html, css

I am making a form and I want multiple input text fields to be equally far from the left side of the screen. However the text to the left of the fields are different lengths causing the input fields to be uneven

```
<form>
    First name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
    <br>
    Last name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>


input{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

How do I set the margins against the left edge of the screen instead of the text.

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle or any screenshot so we can get the issue as by this its not easy to understand or solve your issue. thanx

Comment: That's basically all the code http://jsfiddle.net/qLj2xhtg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give styling to `label` as you can see in the below.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wz688o1/6/)

```
.form label {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 10px;
min-width: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap the First Name: and Last Name: in **label** tags, eg:

```
<form>
<label>First name:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
<label>Last name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
label { display:block }
```

This will make the form fields drop below the labels

Comment: Right I just wanted them all on the same line because I'll be using a lot of inputs